# Dimension minimal of vectors in vector space $V$ with $\dim(V)=n$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Good morning,

If $V$ is a vector space of $\dim(V)=n$, then all vectors in $V$ have $n$ columns at least $v=(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$, or not necessarian.

For example, if $\dim(V)=4$,
and vector $v\in V$, such that $v=(v_1,\cdots,v_m)$ then it is possible with $m< 4$?

Thanks.

Comment: the use of coordinates is just a kind of representation of vectors. Vectors themselves are abstract entities that can be just represented by a letter, regardless of the dimension of the vector space, in the same way we represent functions using letters. However, once we had chosen a basis of the vector space, we can define an isomorphism of $V\to\Bbb F^{\dim V}$ with a representation of vectors using coordinates, where $\Bbb F$ is the field of $V$. If we are using coordinates then the number of coordinates equal the dimension of $V$, not more not less.

Comment: so it is possible $m<n$ or not?,thanks

Comment: No, it is not possible. Case closed.

Comment: ok thanks very much for all answers

Comment: Of course it is possible. Let $V$ be the set of tuples of real numbers of size not larger than $n$ identifying tuples by removing trailing zeros. The sum of two such tuples is defined by forming a tuple of size equal to the largest of the sizes of the summands and adding componentwise. A zero is assumed to be in the place that there are no component to sum. Multiplication by scalars is defined componentwise. The zero is the empty tuple. In this vector space, there are clearly tuples of size $<n$.

Comment: now i am confuse can you give me example with number please

Comment: Let $V$ be the set formed by $()$, $(r)$ for $r\neq0$, $(a,b)$ for $a$ real and $b\neq0$. Define multiplication by scalar and sum componentwise with the requirement that when there are no components to add you assume there is a zero and when a zero is at the back you remove the component. For example $(1,1)+(1,-1)=(1)$ and $(1)+(2,1)=(3,1)$, or $(0,3)+(1,1)=(1,4)$. This is a vector space of dimension $2$. And there are clearly elements like $(1)$. The thing is that the nature of the vectors might be completely unrelated to its linear structure and therefore the dimension.

Comment: The vectors don't need to be tuples of numbers of a certain size, actually they don't even need to be tuples of numbers at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. If a vector space has dimension $4$ then to express a vector as a sum of basis vectors takes $4$ coefficients, one for each basis vector.

You seem to be thinking that a vector in a four dimensional space is always a list of numbers. That's true if the space is $\mathbb{R}^4$. The four basis vectors in that case are the four vectors with one $1$ and three $0$ coordinates.

Comment: so it is impossible $m<n$?.

Comment: i am working in finite field $F$ not $R$?

Comment: It's impossible for any field of scalars. The impossibility follows from the definition of "dimension".

Comment: ok thanks for the answer